# Input buffer not getting flushed even after flushing it using $stdin.iflush

Tags: ruby, file, io, flush, gets

I wrote one project in which there is a class (lets say Class1).

```
class Class1
    attr_accessor :file_var
    def initialize(input_file)
                    @file_var = YAML.load_file(input_file)
            end
    .....some member function in which I read the input_file using file_var......
    end
```

Now I took the object of this Class1 in Class2 as a member

```
class Class2
 attr_accessor :f

     def initialize(input_file)
                   f = Class1.new(input_file)     
        end
        .....some member function in which I am using the read items from input_file......
        end
    end
```

Till this point it was working fine but when I added a member function to Class2 in which I was taking input from the user using the below 3 instructions

```
puts "Enter the input"
$stdin.iflush #instead of this I used other flush commands also listed on Google but it didn't work.
input = gets.chomp
```

**Now the main problem is that it is not stopping for me to give the input , the above commands were in a loop so it didnot stop even once for me to give the input , it was automatically filling the input in the input buffer.**

**And when I displayed the value stored in gets , surprisingly it displayed the data that file_var(data_accessor of class1) read from input_file(that I gave as argument to its constructor). I have no idea how that data came into gets**. Further I thought of closing the file buffer file_var but it was not possible as per the requirements of this program.

Solutions are welcomed!!!

Comment: I can't follow your code, try posting a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I understand but this is most minimized example that I could explain from my project. I only explained those snippets which may have a role in the input problem.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that you're having this problem _precisely_ because you don't understand which snippets may have a role in it. Creating an MCVE could help you discover the solution.

Comment: Reason 1:  I explained Class1 to give an insight that i am reading file through a  buffer.
Reason 2: I explained Class2 to make you know that there is very little relationship between that buffer that the buffer I am using in the member function mentioned later. Reason 3: I gave the small snippet from the member function because that was the actual thing which is giving problem to me. I hope this will justify why I gave this much long code